# How to calculate Future date in django using another column data?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a column that has different dates, and I wanna make a new column with this column value + some period and get the future date in another column for each object
How can I write that in Django models?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save function in your django model and have the field automatically calculated on save.

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if !self.id: # check if this is a new object.
            self.secondDateTime = self.firstDateTime + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```